# in gnomes task overview highlighted window titles are unreadable after upgrade to 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, gnome

i just upgraded to 16.04 and noticed that i can not read titles of the windows when they're hovered.
Here is a picture of my problem:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by the "Native window placement" gnome extension.
I guess this is a bug.

You can disable it with the following steps:

- open Tweak Tool
- go to section Extensions
- turn off Native window placement

<del>Maybe you can file a bug report to get this fixed.</del>

UPDATE:
Seems that this has already been fixed, maybe it is not yet distributed in 16.04: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=758976

---

**Quick Hack**: You can fix the issue with follwoing steps

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/native-window-placement@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/extension.js
```

And inserting in line 413:

```
this._parentActor.set_child_above_sibling(title, border);
```

Save && logout && login